# Is a sequentially continuous map $f:E'\to E'$ continuous?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity, locally-convex-spaces

[I have read](https://mathoverflow.net/a/165297) that for a separable complete locally convex space $E$, any sequentially continuous linear map $f:E'\to \mathbb{K}$ is continuous (where $E'$ is equipped with the weak*-topology).

Is there any similar result for a linear map $f:E'\to E'$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $E$ be a separable complete locally convex space, $f:(E',w^*)\to (E',w^*)$ a sequentially continuous linear map and $ev_x:E'\ni x'\mapsto ev_x(x')=x'(x)\in \mathbb K$ the evaluation map. Then:

\begin{align}
u_n\xrightarrow{w^*} u\quad&\Longrightarrow\quad f(u_n)\xrightarrow{w^*} f(u)\\
&\Longrightarrow\quad f(u_n)[x]\xrightarrow{} f(u)[x],\quad\forall \ x\in E\\
&\Longrightarrow\quad ev_x\circ f(u_n)\xrightarrow{} ev_x\circ f(u),\quad\forall \ x\in E
\end{align}
This shows that $ev_x\circ f:(E',w^*)\to \mathbb K$ is sequentially continuous for all $x\in E$ and thus, by the result in the post, $ev_x\circ f:(E',w^*)\to \mathbb K$ is continuous for all $x\in E$. It follows that the map $f:(E',w^*)\to (E',w^*)$ is continuous.

So the answer is yes, there is a similar result:

> For a separable complete locally convex space $E$, any sequentially continuous linear map $f:E'\to E'$ is continuous (where $E'$ is equipped with the weak*-topology).

[Solution based on [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2098687/70305) of [@LeBtz](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/238388/lebtz)]