# Why do we want $C^\infty_c$ to be complete in distribution theory?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I am studying distribution theory. Denoting by $C_c^\infty$ the space of infinitely diferenciable function with compact support. Many authors point out the topology generated by the norms on the space $C_c^\infty(K)$ with $K$ compact (thats is the funcions in $C_c^\infty$ with support in $K$) is not complete to justify the introduction of the machinery of inductive limit topology on $C_c^\infty$ to turn it complete. Well, completeness is certainly usefull, however up to now I did not see where exactly the theory break down, without completness.

Somebody could give me some hints? Maybe it arises in applications...

Sincerely.

**Edit - A kind of self answer:** Let $C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$ equipped with the non complete topology, it is the topology corresponding to the uniform conergence (of any derivatives) on the compacts (I am right?). Now, let $\Lambda\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)*$ (the algebraic dual), $\Lambda$ is continuous implies $\Lambda$ is continuous on any $C^\infty_c(K)$ but the converse is false. Take $\varphi_n=\xi(x-n)$ with $\xi$ in $C^\infty_c$ with support in $[0,1]$ and $\int \xi =1$. We have $\varphi_n \to 0$ (as well as its derivatives) uniformely on the compact, but
$$\Lambda(\varphi_n) = \int \varphi_n = 1 \neq \Lambda(0)$$
also for any compact $K$ there exists a constant $C>0$ such that:
$$|\Lambda(\varphi)| \leq C\sup_{x\in K} |\varphi|$$
so we have no "good" continuity criterion for the linear form. The inductive limit topology provides the good one since bounded subset belongs to a $C_c^\infty(K)$.
Is I am right!? If it is the case, it is confuse to me, because all the textbook I found, such as the one of Rudin say something like: "this topo is not complete, so let construct an other one which turn it complete" to justify the construction and this messed up. It seems (to me) the problem is more about characterization of continuous linear form on $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$, and for free we get completeness...

Comment: "up to now I did not see" so till where have you seen?

Comment: I see up to the definition of the dual space (distributions) and its topology too.

Comment: I found that:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2099312 which may justify the deriation of distribution from D' to D' is a continuous map... But it is not an iff, and It should be somewhere else a deep reason to force the space to be complete right?

Comment: An other possibility, seems to be, more than completness, the inductive limit topology allows a good identifiction of continuity because this is the one restrict to each C_c^\infty(K) fits with their topology (and ths one is metrizable and complete). Mybe it is because that spce has both property :)

Comment: Yes, I think the restriction to compacts being so nice, is an important factor.

Comment: Thanks Teresa, I edit my comment.

Comment: Yes. The point is, that completeness is a by-product (comes for free) of the inductive limit construction. The inductive limit construction is what is the key here : it provides results that are desirable, not the completeness itself. The point is, that the space itself is of bump functions i.e. those that are smooth with compact support . We want a functional to be *determined* by what it does on each of these compact sets (including continuity), and for that the inductive limit topology is perfect.

Comment: Which also means you are absolutely  right : Rudin should not be emphasizing the non-completeness of the usual topology, but rather the fact that a linear functional could behave well on compacts but behave poorly in general : something which is not desirable in light of the fact we have compactly supported functions. Completeness comes for free. Of course, that doesn't mean it is not useful, but it is nice to have it without too much effort.

Comment: Many thanks Teresa for your comments and kind help!

Comment: you are welcome!

Comment: Why would anyone want to put on the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$ a topology other than the usual topology? The same can be said of the vector space $C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R})$. Completeness is just one of the many desirable features of the appropriate topology one would lose if one used another topology.